# Same code produces different output depending on if curly braces are present

Tags: c++, debugging

I have this code:

```
int main() {

int list[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
int max = 0, min = 0, small, large;

for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {

    if(list[max] < list[j]) {
        max = j;
        large = list[max];
    }

    if(list[min] > list[j]) {
        min = j;
        small = list[min];
    }

    cout << "Maximum :" << large << endl;
    cout << "Minimum :" << small << endl << endl;
}
```

the `small` will not be correct in the above code.

**Output:**

```
Maximum :-1482404720
Minimum :0

Maximum :2
Minimum :0

Maximum :3
Minimum :0

Maximum :4
Minimum :0

Maximum :5
Minimum :0

Maximum :6
Minimum :0

Maximum :7
Minimum :0

Maximum :8
Minimum :0

Maximum :9
Minimum :0

Maximum :10
Minimum :0
```

However, the same code with the curly braces omitted like this, will work:

```
    if(list[max] < list[j]) 
        max = j;
        large = list[max];


    if(list[min] > list[j]) 
        min = j;
        small = list[min];
```

the above code now properly displays the minimum and maximum values.

**Output:**

```
Maximum :1
Minimum :1

Maximum :2
Minimum :1

Maximum :3
Minimum :1

Maximum :4
Minimum :1

Maximum :5
Minimum :1

Maximum :6
Minimum :1

Maximum :7
Minimum :1

Maximum :8
Minimum :1

Maximum :9
Minimum :1

Maximum :10
Minimum :1
```

Why is this happening? I've asked my lecturer and she doesn't know either, so I decided to ask here instead.

Comment: Try some other inputs for testing - 1 up to 10 in order means the last number checked is 10, so this might be working by accident.

Comment: Pretty basic thing for a lecturer not to know ..

Comment: The "same code" as you say, "if curly braces are present": ***is not the same code***. You may be thinking of semantics of another language like Python. But perhaps the best thing to resolve your confusion, would be for you to explain what you think the purpose of the curly braces is?

Comment: If your lecturer doesn't such a basic thing, you should really think of changing lecturers, since you will learn nothing useful, with the current one.

Comment: @doctorlove I also tried other inputs, like 10 until 1 (descending), and I noticed the min has a logic error, it will always be false if the input is 1 to 10 (ascending) so yes it does seem to be working by accident

Comment: You should file a formal complain for the lecturer's incompetence.

Comment: @CraigYoung curly braces are optional, but it's good practice to put it, the code is from my lecturer, she omits the curly braces all the time...I only caught this error when I placed the curly braces, because that's what i've been doing all the while...

Comment: @ShawnLaw That **doesn't** answer his question. What do you think, that curly braces does?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius curly braces are to mark the start and end of whatever it encloses, and whatever statements that are enclosed by the curly braces will be executed...

Comment: @ShawnLaw Curly braces are not something to be considered "optional". It changes what lines get executed when (if at all). Since you tagged this as a debugging question, perhaps the real thing you should be asking yourself is how many times each **if** condition evaluates to **true** when you run the code. And based on your understanding of what the curly braces do, it might reveal why `small` is not set correctly.

Comment: @ShawnLaw No, not really. Curly braces form a compound statement. Statements such as `if`, `while` etc. execute **only** the statement immediately after it. Whether it is a simple statement, or a compound statement. Indentation means nothing in C++. It is important only for readability. That should have been explained by your lecturer, and, as has been already suggested, you should file a formal complaint for your lecturers incompetence, due to not having such basic knowledge about the thing they are teaching.

Comment: I am aware and also suspicious about my lecturer's incompetence, but in my college, there is only 1 lecturer teaching this subject, and it's her, nothing can be done about it unfortunately...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare

```
int list[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int max=0, min=0, small, large;
```

you have not initialised `small` or `large`.

When you go into the loop, `min` is zero, so the `if` is never true for your numbers:

```
if(list[min] > list[j]) {
    min = j;
    small = list[min];
}
```

since they happen to be increasing.
This means you never intialise `small`.

If you have

```
if(list[min] > list[j]) 
    min = j;
    small = list[min];
```

instead, this means the same as

```
if(list[min] > list[j]) {
    min = j;
}
    small = list[min];
```

or

```
if(list[min] > list[j]) 
    min = j;
}
small = list[min];
```

which means `small` is intialised.

Since your example `list` is increasing, you got lucky and `max` did work either way.
Try various inputs.
And intialise your variables.

Comment: I already tried different inputs, I also tried isolating the individual if statements, and I found out that the condition "list[min] > list[j]" is never true, and I got lucky with "list[max] < list[j]" because the numbers so happen to be in ascending order...I knew about this logic error, the only thing confusing me was the curly braces, because my lecturer omits them every time...the way you explained the curly braces and written them, now I fully understand why it does and does not work, thank you doctorlove...

Comment: @ShawnLaw If you lecturer always omits braces but uses the indentation you show in your question, then she's thinking of a different language and clearly doesn't understand braces in C++. She needs to improve her C++ knowledge before tying to teach it and should stick to the languages she knows for now. I suggest you refer her to [Algirdas's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51589333/same-code-produces-different-output-depending-on-if-curly-braces-are-present#comment90144608_51589333) to help her learn.

Answer (score 0):

If you miss the curly braces the looping/conditional statement will be applied only to the next statement.
so your second statement followed by "if(list[max] < list[j]) " and "if(list[min] > list[j])" is not applicable to "large = list[max];" and "small = list[min];" respectively.

hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not due to with or without curly brackets. Your code has bugs. It is working without brackets just accidentally. Try below code and improve on it -

```
int main() {

    int list[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int max=0, min=0, small, large;

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {

        if(list[max] < list[j]) {
            max = j;
        }
        else if(list[min] > list[j]) {
            min = j;
        }
    }

    large = list[max];
    small = list[min];

    cout << "Maximum :" << large << endl;
    cout << "Minimum :" << small << endl;
}
```